# R apply with a vector parameter

Tags: r, apply, mapply

I am trying to apply the `ppoibin` (poisson binomial probabilities) function from the poibin package to each row in a dataframe. This function takes two parameters: an integer and a vector of probabilities. My data takes the form:

```
p <- matrix(c(0.046, 0.046, 0.323,
              0.122, 0.122, 0.490,
              0.122, 0.122, 0.490),
            3 , 3, byrow = TRUE)
dat <- data.frame(k = c(0, 1, 0))
dat$p <- p
```

Within each row, `k` is the integer where I want to evaluate the probability. The `p[,1]` `p[,2]` ... `p[,n]` values are the probability parameters for the function.

I can do this row-by-row in a loop and get the correct result:

```
for (i in c(1:nrow(dat))) {
  dat$prob[i] <- ppoibin(dat$k[i], dat$p[i,])
}
```

I'd like to avoid the loop. However, if I try to apply the function directly to the dataframe using

```
dat$prob2 <- ppoibin(dat$k, dat$p[,])
```

I get an incorrect result. I suspect this requires using `apply` or more likely `mapply`, but I'm not sure how.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
dat$prob2 <- sapply(1:nrow(dat), function(i) ppoibin(dat$k[i], dat$p[i,]))
```